# Dragging on Rotated Android View

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, rotation, android-view

I've been creating a game which played by 2 player on different side of the phone so I created 2 View for the play area of both player and place the first one by 180 degree rotated at the top of the screen and another one without rotation in the bottom. But when I rotated the top View the element in that View cannot be drag. So I want to know how can I rotate the View and still can drag the element in it? (dragging in another View without rotation works well)

here is my code

creating and set animation to rotate the View

```
RotateAnimation anime_rotate = (RotateAnimation) AnimationUtils
            .loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
    anime_rotate.setFillAfter(true);

LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linear.buildDrawingCache(true);
    DrawView drawView1 = new DrawView(this, new Rect(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH,
            WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2));
    drawView1.setAnimation(anime_rotate);
    DrawView drawView2 = new DrawView(this, new Rect(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH,
            WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2));

linear.addView(drawView1, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2);
    linear.addView(drawView2, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2);

setContentView(linear);
```

the animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0" android:toDegrees="180" android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%" android:duration="0" />
```